# Intersect multiple lists in a dictonary using python

Tags: python

This has been bugging me for a whole day. I need to send emails to different person, some emails may have multiple recipients, and some recipient receives multiple emails.

So suppose I have a dictionary like this:

```
{
    'email4': ['msg1', 'msg4', 'msg5'], 
    'email2': ['msg1', 'msg3'], 
    'email3': ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg4'], 
    'email1': ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']
}
```

And I want to produce something like:

```
{
    'email1, email2, email3, email4': ['msg1'],
    'email1, email3': ['msg2'],
    'email1, email2': ['msg3'],
    'email3, email4': ['msg4'],
    'email4': ['msg5']
}
```

I figured it would be a multiple intersection on both keys and values of the dictionary sort of thing, anyway, you get the idea.

Quick question, how do I do this in python.

Thanks for any help, have a nice day.

### Update

1. why use email(s) as keys
   Let's say I'm gonna send email to email address 4, instead of sending msg1, msg4, and msg5 in separate emails, I want to combine them into 1 email.
2. Tuple keys
   It's just a demonstration, I of course can use tuples, but how's that gonna solve my problem?

Thanks all

Comment: Are you sure you want a comma-delimited string as your dictionary key instead of a tuple?

Comment: i did't understood your logic. put clarification here and you code.

Answer (score 2):

Example using [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of sets as intermediate data structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

messages = { 
    'email4': ['msg1', 'msg4', 'msg5'],
    'email2': ['msg1', 'msg3'],
    'email3': ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg4'],
    'email1': ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']
}

intermediate = defaultdict(set)

for email, msgs in messages.items():
    for msg in msgs:
        intermediate[msg].add(email)

inverted = {tuple(v): k for k, v in intermediate.items()}
pprint(inverted)

# {('email2', 'email1'): 'msg3',
#  ('email3', 'email1'): 'msg2',
#  ('email4',): 'msg5',
#  ('email4', 'email2', 'email3', 'email1'): 'msg1',
#  ('email4', 'email3'): 'msg4'}
```

Answer (score 1):

First suggestions: index on messages and key to list of recipients, easy to work with:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

data = {
    'email4': ['msg1', 'msg4', 'msg5'], 
    'email2': ['msg1', 'msg3'], 
    'email3': ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg4'], 
    'email1': ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']
}

result = defaultdict(list)

for addr, msgs in data.iteritems():
    for msg in msgs:
        result[msg].append(addr)

pprint(result)
```

If all you want is to combine the messages:

```
for addr, msgs in data.iteritems():
    data[addr] = '\n'.join(msgs)

print data
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make a dictionnary that is the "reverse" of the one you have now : one where keys are the messages and values the recipients :

```
{
    'msg1': ['email1', 'email2', 'email3', 'email4'],
    'msg2': ['email1', 'email3'],
    ...
```

To do so, you just have to go through your dictionnary once.

Once you have this second dictionnary, solving your problem is rather straightforward.